# Cant get the OAuth2 FB Tornado example

Tags: tornado

Here is initial code, from [the Example](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/demos/facebook/facebook.py)

```
class AuthLoginHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):
@tornado.web.asynchronous
def get(self):
    my_url = (self.request.protocol+"://"+self.request.host+"/auth/login?next="+tornado.escape.url_escape(self.get_argument("next", "/")))
    print my_url
    if self.get_argument("code", False):
        self.get_authenticated_user(redirect_uri=my_url,client_id=facebook_api_key, client_secret=facebook_secret,code=self.get_argument("code"),callback=self._on_auth)
        print "th"
        print self.get_argument("code")
        return
    self.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri=my_url,client_id=facebook_api_key,extra_params={"scope": "read_stream"})

def _on_auth(self, user):
    if not user:
        raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, "Facebook auth failed")
    self.set_secure_cookie("user", tornado.escape.json_encode(user))
    self.redirect(self.get_argument("next", "/"))
```

What i dont get is:

```
if self.get_argument("code", False):
```

What does this means? Because if i make `self.get_argument("code")` i get error that there is **Missing argument code**

Why negating and then calling this argument `code=self.get_argument("code")`

I've checked the documentation, and what i understand is that `False` to change `Strip=True` by default!

Can you please explain me the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of 'code' as a flag: 'if the user is verified by Facebook'.

```
If self.get_argument("code", False):
     # Happy we are now authorized by Facebook
     Get the Facebook user who is logged in (and then call '_on_auth')
     return 
(Else): 
     Ask for authorization
```

The Tornado auth code is [here](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/auth.py)

Simple version:
Dont try and set the 'code' variable - this is for Facebook to do.

Comment: so it's kind of if a user is not logged yet, show the login page?

Comment: Yes - but remember it is the login page served from Facebook not your app

Comment: and tornado will use the cookie generated